# Start selected launcher instead of the lockscreen

Tags: android, lockscreen, android-launcher

Im playing with a lockscreen and selcted my second activity as home launcher now. 
So the home key is locked on lockscreen.

How do i start now the nova launcher (or another custom launcher) instead of my empty layout from second activity when I press the home key outside from lockscreen?
I'm a bit confused on this topic.
**EDIT:**
I have currently that configurations for my lockscreen activity in my manifest:

```
<activity
        android:name=".LockscreenActivity"
        android:excludeFromRecents="true"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance"
        android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
        android:label="Lockscreen"
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <!-- The following two intent-filters are the key to set homescreen -->
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Any i found out that i can use the onNewIntent. But it dont work :/

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    Log.e("debug", "actions: " + intent.getAction());
    if (Intent.ACTION_MAIN.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        Log.e("debug", "ACTION MAIN");
        Intent i = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.teslacoilsw.launcher");
        startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

Every time the lockscreenactivity will open when i press the home button.

Comment: Please paste some code that you've tried.

Comment: @Tauqir Have nothing ^^ found nothing by google

Comment: Resolve the launcher intent and choose the google launcher by package name.

Comment: Can you share me code pls ? :) (i changed google launcher to the nova launcher)

Comment: @323go i edited my question